# What are some useful resources for simple two-body quantum simulation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, quantum-entanglement, computational-physics, software

Are there available, commercial or free, numerical packages for simulating quantum dynamics that have built-in tools especially for quantum mechanics?

For the purpose of this question, I want to simulate two charged particles with a 1/r potential. I want to see how entanglement of the two charges affects each other's motion. It's such a simple problem that I'd think there would be packages for simulating such behaviour. I don't want to have to re-implement some PDE solver that already exists.

Answer (score -1):

I never tried it, but MCTDH-X (available at www.ultracold.org) seems to fit the description:

> "MCTDH-X is a collection of computer programs and bash scripts to accurately solve the time-dependent Schrödinger equation for many interacting identical particles and visualize the obtained solutions."
>
> "The MCTDH-X software solves the many-body Schrödinger equation by using a general many-body ansatz, that goes beyond the mainstream mean-field approaches like the Gross-Pitavskii or Hartree-Fock equation. Thus, fragmentation and correlations can be treated with the program"